# How can I remove MVC2's validation messages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, client-side-validation

I am using ASP.NET C# MVC2 and I have the following field within a model with the following data annotation validation attributes:

```
[DisplayName("My Custom Field")]
[Range(long.MinValue, long.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "The stated My Custom Field value is invalid!")]
public long? MyCustomField{ get; set; }
```

In the form this field should allow the user to leave it blank and display a validation message should the user attempt to enter a value that cannot be expressed as a number. From a validation point of view, this is working as intended and displaying the following error messages:

> The stated My Custom Field value is invalid!
>
> The field My Custom Field must be a number.

The first validation message is the custom validation message that I wrote and the second validation message is the one the MVC2 automatically generates. I need to get rid of the second one since its redundant. How do I do this? In my view I have the following markup

```
<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
   { %>
   <%:Html.ValidationSummary(false)%>
   <% Html.ValidateFor(m => m.MyCustomField); %>
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue you have here is because the property being bound is a numeric, and model binding is automatically handling the fact that the string could not be converted to a number.  It's not the `RangeAttribute`'s doing.

You might instead consider having a new property as a `string` and deriving your own `RangeAttribute` which works at the string level, parsing the number first.

Then you have your existing property wrap that string:

```
 [DisplayName("My Custom Field")]
 [MyCustomRangeAttribute(/* blah */)] //<-- the new range attribute you write
 public string MyCustomFieldString
 {
   get; set;
 }

 public int? MyCustomField
 {
   get 
   { 
     if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MyCustomField))
       return null;
     int result;
     if(int.TryParse(MyCustomField, out result))
       return result;
     return null;
   }    
   set
   {
      MyCustomFieldString = value != null ? value.Value.ToString() : null;
   }
 }
```

Your code can continue to work on the `int?` property quite happily, but  - all model binding is done on the string property.

You will also ideally add `[Bind(Exclude"MyCustomField")]` to the model type - to ensure that MVC doesn't try and bind the `int?` field.  Or you can just make it `internal`.  If it's in the web project and you only need to reference it in the web project.

You could also consider the really hacky approach - and finding that error in your controller method via `ModelState.Errors` and removing it before you return your view result...

Comment: Hi andras, thanks for the suggestions. I knew about the using of string as datatype but in this case I really need to keep the datatype as is and I can't use hacky methods. This solution I need to apply to a big project that will require constant support.

Comment: Unfortunately, then you'll have to look at re-working the `DefaultModelBinder` - as I believe that is where the validation message is originated.  You say it really needs to be kept as an `int`; but in my experience you should be prepared to be more flexible on your model types; unless you want to write a lot of custom code.  Anyway - with my updated code you won't even notice a difference at the back-end...

Comment: @WilliamCalleja  sorry I wrote my comment before updating the code, thinking I would be fast...  It's updated now.  Not a changed answer, though I'm afraid.